# Intense Debate PHP Class?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, comments, intense-debate

I'm working with [Intense Debate](http://intensedebate.com/). I keep looking for a way to integrate a non-javascript version in my websites… and I was hoping there would be some sort of PHP Class available but I can not find one on google, and the API they provide is a Javascript API for customization.

What I want to do is use Intensedebate like wordpress does but in my own script. They said this in their FAQ on SEO:

> IntenseDebate outputs the standard WordPress comments enabling your comments to still be indexed by search engines that ignore JavaScript, while ensuring that visitors surfing with JavaScript disabled will be able to interact with comments made in IntenseDebate. **Readers with JS disabled can comment in the original WP system and those comments will be imported into ID**.

That is actually what I am trying to achieve with my own custom PHP script. But there is no documentation on this…

You can see what I mean on my temporary test page: http://repost.be/index.php
As you can see when you disable javascript… you can't see the comments, nor comment.

That is by the way just an HTML page with custom Javascript that Intensedebate provided.
Any thoughts on how I can interact with their API properly or find a PHP class that does so?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with IntenseDebate, but from what I can gather from their help docs and general comments on the net, their system absolutely requires Javascript to run. There's no way to use their data through another API.

Apparently IntenseDebate gives WP users the option to sync their comments with IntenseDebate through the provided Wordpress plugin. Maybe you

Comment: Well that kind of is the point isn't it? If Wordpress can capture the comments and send them to IntenseDebate for storing then so should you be able to do that with any PHP script. I know how to build comments but I just don't know how to send them to ID for processing.